# C# performance much faster when using anonymous types over named types

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datatable, anonymous-types

I have a file of 280,000 lines of data that I want to read, put into a datatable, and eventually save. I have done it, but whilst tweaking the finished code I found a noticeable improvement in performance when using an anonymous type instead of a named type. I have created a small sample below that demonstrates the difference in performance that I am seeing:

```
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            // One column for each property
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(IISLog)))
                dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);

            var items = rows.Select(data => new //IISLog
            {
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(data[0]),
                Time = data[1],
                ServerIPAddress = data[2],
                Method = data[3],
                URIStem = data[4],
                URIQuery = data[5],
                ServerPort = int.Parse(data[6]),
                UserName = data[7],
                ClientIPAddress = data[8],
                UserAgent = data[9],
                Referrer = data[10],
                ProtocolStatus = int.Parse(data[11]),
                ProtocolSubStatus = int.Parse(data[12]),
                Win32Status = long.Parse(data[13]),
                TimeTaken = int.Parse(data[14])
            }).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + stop.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Date, item.Time, item.ServerIPAddress, item.Method, item.URIStem,
                    item.URIQuery, item.ServerPort, item.UserName, item.ClientIPAddress, item.UserAgent,
                    item.Referrer, item.ProtocolStatus, item.ProtocolSubStatus, item.Win32Status, item.TimeTaken);
            }

            stop.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + stop.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

And here is the IISLog class:

```
    public class IISLog
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string ServerIPAddress { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public string URIStem { get; set; }
        public string URIQuery { get; set; }
        public int ServerPort { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string ClientIPAddress { get; set; }
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
        public string Referrer { get; set; }
        public int ProtocolStatus { get; set; }
        public int ProtocolSubStatus { get; set; }
        public long Win32Status { get; set; }
        public int TimeTaken { get; set; }
    }
```

If I run the code as is, the console prints out elapsed times of 1811ms at the first print, and 2203ms when it finishes. If I uncomment "//IISLog", the console prints out elapsed times of 11807ms and 21939ms. The data in the file is IIS log data, so it is of the format:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2024-01-05 04:27:03 1.1.1.1 GET / - 443 - 2.2.2.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+NetcraftSurveyAgent/1.0;++info@netcraft.com) - 302 0 0 5925
```

Again, this is only sample code used to highlight what I'm seeing, but the performance issue exists in it. **I'm just curious as to why the anonymous types are so much faster in being created, and why iterating them when adding the values to the datatable is also dramatically faster?**

EDIT: Removed nullable int types from class

EDIT 2: I have tested the code in isolation in a new .NET Framework 4.8 project and they are both performing the same. This obviously points to something in the project that is causing the issue.

Comment: one observation: there's a difference in the integers (x5) - in the `IISLog` type they're all nullable, but in the anon-type the inferred type (from `int.Parse` etc) is non-nullable; this changes both the memory usage per row and adds minor overheads into both get and set; this *might* be one of a handful of factors; maybe try `(int?)int.Parse(...)` etc, so that the two versions are identical? Anonymous types are also implemented with naked fields, but that *shouldn't* be as much of a factor (I would expect the JIT to elide those properties back to direct field access)

Comment: additional observation: anonymous types are `sealed`; maybe add `sealed` to `IISLog`

Comment: This is a naive way of performance testing. Use a tool like [benchmark.net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html).

Comment: perhaps tangential: if this is for `SqlBulkCopy` usage, note that there are ways of using `SqlBulkCopy` direct from your `items` query (without even the `ToList()`), avoiding a translation step - let me know if that is relevant, and I can provide an example

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't actually need the nullable types, so I've changed them to ints. However, it hasn't made a difference, neither has the sealed class! Good suggestions though!

Comment: side note: depending on the framework that you're running on, the order of properties fetched via reflection (`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties`) may be entirely undefined - which means it is *possible* that your columns end up in a random order; I don't think this is relevant here, but: you might want to check on that

Comment: additional additional: you don't *need* the list here, even if you aren't using `SqlBulkCopy`; remove the `.ToList()` - this will mean that you don't need to allocate a series of increasingly large arrays (which is what `.ToList()` does behind the scenes) - note that the timing on the existing line is then meaningless, as you haven't *done* anything, but: it should be faster; there's a ton of other things I could trim here, but this isn't answering the question of class vs anon-type

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for all the suggestions, I've just tested the code in a brand new project and it works fine. It looks like there must be something in the existing project causing the issue, which opens up a whole new can of worms!

Comment: @MarcGravell RE the list - yes I know. It was just for testing purposes that it exists like that! I wanted to see how much time was taken iterating vs how much time was taken generating the items.

Comment: another delta: anon-types in this scenario use a single hidden constructor - as though you had used `new TheType(Convert.ToDateTime(data[0]), data[1], ...)`

Comment: Instead of creating new objects (anonymous or typed), you could use the [DataTable.LoadDataRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow?view=net-8.0) which has an array of objects as argument. You don't need the linq query for this. You can put each value in it. I think this would be faster.  Also, where does the "rows" come from? instead of setting up all rows in a rows collection, you can fill the `dataTable` directly, on receiving the rows.